# Construct dynamic SQL query using values from table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table logs where I log operations on various tables which contains the following sample data:

```
id    reference_table     reference_table_id
1     comments            53
2     reports             75
```

The column reference_table refers to actual tables in the database. The column reference_table_id refers to the corresponding id (primary key) of the tables in reference_table column.

The reference_table and reference_table_id values are dynamic (so I can't predict what values they will contain).

I would like to construct an SQL query to get all values in logs where:

```
reference_table.id = reference_table_id
```

For example, with this sample data I want to get all logs where

```
comments.id = 53 AND reports.id = 75
```

But obviously the query has to be dynamically constructed.

I hope you guys understand what I mean. Thanks for any help

Comment: *with this sample data I want to get all logs where* Your data does not define how the tables are joined (may be ignored if `reference_table_id` is referenced to PK/unique field/expression) and what data must be retrieved from each separate table.

Comment: This kind of problem is highly symptomatic of poor schema design

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT CONCAT( 'SELECT ',
               GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( reference_table,
                                     '.id AS ',
                                     reference_table,
                                     '_id' 
                                   ) 
                           ),
               ' FROM ',
               GROUP_CONCAT( reference_table ),
               ' WHERE ',
               GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( reference_table,
                                     '.id = ',
                                     reference_table_id 
                                   )
                             SEPARATOR ' AND '
                           )
             )
FROM logs
/* WHERE ... */
INTO @sql;
/* SELECT @sql; -- check the final query text is correct */
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DROP PREPARE stmt;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=893877f26b5bdc4ec24b9a1da03ec99c)